# How to restore/recover deleted artifacts from JFrog artifactory

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

How to restore/recover artifacts deleted using `jfrog delete rt` from jfrog repository.  Trashcan in jfrog settings are configured to keep the deleted image for 3 weeks.  so I know it is available. But could not find a way to restore it.
JFrog documentation to restore image is not much helpful. https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-recover-deleted-moved-artifacts/

Comment: Have you tried the steps mentioned in the doc you have provided in link? If yes, are there any errors are you facing?

Comment: May be restore? Rest API Documentation: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RestoreItemfromTrashCan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have the Trash Can [activated](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+Artifactory#ConfiguringArtifactory-TrashCanSettings), you should follow the [instructions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Browsing+Artifacts#BrowsingArtifacts-RestoringArtifactsfromtheTrashCan) specified in the Artifactory documentation:
When enabled, the trash can is displayed at the bottom of the Artifact Repository Browser and it holds all artifacts or repository paths that have been deleted from local repositories for the period of time specified in the Retention Period field.
Right-click on an item in the trash can gives you the option to Refresh, Restore it to its original location, or Delete permanently.
Right-click on the trash can icon gives you the option to Refresh the whole trash can, Search Trash for specific items

Comment: This worked. Jfrog needs to improve on UI.  I was able to locate the deleted images. Also I found the CLI  to restore from trash can.  Restore is again mv from trashcan to original folder. trashcan is located at  **auto-trashcan** and using ** jfrog rt mv auto-trashcan/<path> <path>**